# Sci-fi novel series about teens fighting a robot proxy war

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for the name of a book series. This was a series I read a while ago. It was about a school for special teenagers who were going to pilot robots to fight proxy wars in outer space. All the teens have some kind of neural network/computer implanted into their brain so they can learn basically anything without thinking about it.

However, the one thing they weren't allowed to learn through the brain computer was coding, because in the book it was illegal to teach a computer how to code on its own, and they had to learn that manually.

The series ends with everybody on Earth getting a brain computer and using them to make the world a better place.

If it helps, this book was either a Truman award or Mark Twain award winner.

Comment: If you could, please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to elicit further details to [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Insignia](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11115434-insignia) S. J. Kincaid. [It was a Truman nominee in 2014](https://thelibrary.org/teens/booklists/tpl_nominees_list.cfm?awardid=28&listid=880).

[image: Insignia book cover, winged logo on red background]

The main protagonist is Tom Raines:

> Tom doesn't seem like a hero. He's a short fourteen-year-old with bad skin. But he has the virtual-reality gaming skills that make him a phenom behind the controls of the battle drones.

The bit with the processors in the brains is:

> Marsh said, “To become a trainee here, Mr. Raines, you have to have a neural processor installed in your head. It’s a very sophisticated computer that interacts directly with your brain. You’re still human afterward, just something extra as well.”
>
> Olivia’s hand squeezed his shoulder. Tom pulled away from it. “You didn’t say anything about—” he began.
>
> “What did you think, son?” General Marsh raised his thin eyebrows. “Our Combatants control machines, and they fight machines. You’ve got quick synapses yourself. But your brain isn’t machine fast. Not yet. Those kids in there? Their brains are.

The ban on computers programming for themselves is described by Major Blackburn in their programming class:

> Blackburn puffed out his cheeks and released his breath very slowly. “I’ve said this before,” he replied, “and I’ll say it again: those neural processors can’t manipulate computer languages the way they do human languages, and there’s a very simple reason for that—it’s illegal. We have federal laws in this country. One such law prohibits self-programming computers. Your neural processor, as a computer, falls under this law.